# nodemailer not sending emails when deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a nodejs code for sending emails, which works when I run it locally but not when I deploy it to heroku

This is the code in question

```js
app.post('/contact', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
        console.log("post contact page");
        console.log("this is req: ");
        console.log(req.body);
        
        let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
        smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'email',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });
        mailOpts = {
            from: req.body.fname + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
            to: 'email',
            subject: 'New message from contact form at your portfolio page',
            text: `${req.body.fname} (${req.body.email}) says: \n \n ${req.body.msg}`
        };
        smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts);

        res.render("pages/Contact");
    });
```

What should I do? Is this a problem with my code or with the heroku deploy?

Comment: The code works so it's probably an environment issue.  Ensure you look for return codes in your calls.  How is gmail resolved to a server?  Does your app connect or does Heroku block outbound connections?  Are you getting your console output?  Do you have any logs?

Comment: How can I check for both of these questions?

Comment: I have never used Heroku but if ti's just a linux you could use tcpdump to see if there is any outbound traffic.  Start with logs, though, and check all return codes.  https://nodemailer.com/smtp/ says there are logger and debug options that would be a good to enable.  Also, you leaked credentials, change them, if real.

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/usage/ shows the callback that you can enable on sendMail.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the port when you initialize nodemailer:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        port: 587,
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: { user: user, pass: pass },
    });
```